# IntelliJ Idea changes pasted code

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, static-import

When pasting Kotlin code from another class with "static" imports, e.g.:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
```

I would like IDE to add import like this

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.*
```

But instead of that IntelliJ Idea (version 2018.1.1) changes the pasted code to

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

and adds

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
```

Is that bug or feature and can I change it?

Comment: In `Settings->General->Auto Import` you will find `Insert imports on paste` with possible values `All/Ask/None`. However I don't think there's a way to tell IntelliJ to use static import by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shortcoming of the current version of the Kotlin plugin. I've filed [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23906) to improve the behavior in future versions.